# How to handle SSL handshake failure in Netty

Tags: ssl, netty

We're implementing SSL on top of Netty. But there's a flaw in current design. The client will retry connecting to server if failed. This is desired in Network or heavy server load issues. But wrong client credentials would cause constant failure.

There're some solutions:

1. The client-server connection can failover to unencrypted mode
   (removing SslHandler from pipeline).
2. Client can die and throw exception on knowing it's SSL exception.

Unfortunately I don't know how to implement this using Netty. A few questions:

1. How to detect it's SSL exception?
2. How to remove the SslHandler from both side safely?

Please help out here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no safe way to downgrade an SSL connection to a plaintext connection.

To detect a handshake failure, you need to implement `userEventTriggered()` handler method:

```
public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) {
    if (evt instanceof SslHandshakeCompletionEvent) {
        if (!((SslHandshakeCompletionEvent) evt).isSuccess()) {
            // handshake failed
        }
    }
}
```

You can also add a listener to the handshake future:

```
ChannelPipeline p = ...;
SslHandler sslHandler = p.get(SslHandler.class);
sslHandler.handshakeFuture().addListener(new FutureListener<Channel> { ... });
```